# Have the Wachowskis explained what significance they intended for the character name "Trinity"?

Tags: the-matrix, names

Many of the characters in *The Matrix* have meaningful names which relate to the role the character plays. For example:

- "Neo" is an anagram of "One" (for The One). Also, one of the many references to Neo as a Christ figure is his surname (Anderson), which means "son of man" -- one of the titles Jesus often used for Himself.
- Morpheus is the name of the Greek god of dreams -- Morpheus the character often speaks of the Matrix as a dream, as well as his dream that the Matrix would be destroyed.
- Persephone is the queen of the underworld in Greek mythology, and the character of the same name is the "queen" of the Matrix underworld controlled by her husband, the Merovingian.

Trinity's name is clearly related to the Christian [Trinity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trinity) (God is one but consists of three Persons -- the Father, Son, and Holy Spirit), but unlike the aforementioned characters it's less clear how her name relates to her role in the franchise. She doesn't seem to represent God since (a) Neo is much more clearly a God figure (specifically the Son of the Trinity) and (b) she dies but does not resurrect.

Perhaps Trinity's name is intended to point to the three main protagonists of the films (Neo, Morpheus, and Trinity herself). However, it doesn't make sense in-universe why Trinity would give herself that hacker name before such a trinity existed. Furthermore, while it's clear that Neo would represent the Son and Morpheus would probably represent the Father, it's not as obvious to see how Trinity would represent the Holy Spirit.

**Have the Wachowskis explained what significance they intended for the character name "Trinity"?** I am primarily interested in the out-of-universe reason for the character's name, though I am also interested in the in-universe reason why the character would give herself the hacker alias "Trinity" (especially if that reason sheds light on the out-of-universe significance of her character's name). If the Wachowskis have not spoken on the matter I am also interested in educated guesses as to the significance of the name.

Comment: Isn't it just a name like "Mona Lisa"?

Comment: She dies but Neo returns her back to life by re activating her heart.

Comment: @atakanyenel And then she dies again in the real world en route to the machine city.

Comment: @DavidTonhofer "Lisa" is a name, "Mona" is a title or form of address - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mona_Lisa#Title_and_subject

Comment: @Null While reading your question, I was reminded of the first Matrix movie, where Neo (Son of Man) dies. But then Trinity confesses her love for him, and brings him back to life. This could be said to model what happened to Jesus when he died. The bible describes that God raised Him from the dead through the power of the Holy Spirit, the 2 parts of the Trinity bringing back to life the 3rd part.

Comment: @user2636032 That's an interesting perspective. When I rejected Trinity as representing the Holy Spirit I was thinking primarily of the Holy Spirit proceeding from the Father and the Son...which just doesn't work when Morpheus represents the Father and Neo the Son. But the character Trinity does fill that role of the Holy Spirit. You should post that as an answer -- I would certainly upvote it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Carrie-Anne Moss (the actress who played Trinity) [said this in an event](https://www.matrixfans.net/movies/the-matrix/carrie-anne-moss-chat-transcript/)

> guest-DigitalSelf: What does the name, Trinity, symbolize in the movie?

> Carrie-Anne: It symbolizes a lot of different things. It symbolizes the Holy Trinity, being part of the energy of three, Morpheus, Neal[sic], and myself. And it can mean whatever you want it to mean.

The number three plays a significant role in the Matrix

- Trinity is in [Room 303](https://matrix.fandom.com/wiki/Room_303) when the first film starts. Neo's apartment is Room 101
- Three agents guard Morpheus in the tower where he is being held

  > Tank: Neo, this is loco. They’ve got Morpheus in a military controlled building. Even if you somehow got inside, those are agents holding him. Three of them. I want Morpheus back too, but what you’re talking about is suicide.
- The phone Neo has to reach at the end of the first Matrix is also in room 303
- Neo faces three agents at the start of *The Matrix Reloaded*
- To gain access to The Source, Morpheus notes that there are three ships to carry out his plan, a number he believes is providential

  > Morpheus: All of our lives we have fought this war. Tonight I believe we can end it. Tonight is not an accident. There are no accidents. We have not come here by chance. I do not believe in chance when I see 3 objectives, 3 captains, 3 ships. I do not see coincidence, I see providence, I see purpose. I believe it is our fate to be here. It is our destiny. I believe this night holds for each and every one of us the very meaning of our lives.
- The machine invasion comes to Zion via Gate 3

  > The ship is under attack, sustaining heavy damage. But at its present velocity, it’ll reach Gate 3 in twelve minutes.

Comment: Good points, thanks. Is Carrie-Anne Moss' quote supposed to read "...Morpheus, **Neo**, and myself"?

Comment: @Null I suspect it was a transcription error, but that's a good point. Added sic, to indicate that typo is as it appears

Comment: Whoever transcribed this obviously knows the movie really well.

Comment: "The phone Neo has to reach at the end of the first Matrix is also in room 303" In the same hotel where Trinity started the movie, no less (the neon sign says "Heart o' the City hotel" or something like that). So it's not just the same room number, it is the exact same room. Smith notices that this is indeed the same place, and gets to the room ahead of Neo.

Comment: @Null Maybe she meant [John Neal](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0623630/?ref_=ttfc_fc_cr177), who was one of the special effects artists on the film?  (Sorry, according to IMDB, the only Neal involved with the film.)

Answer (score 8):

Along with a reference to the Christian triune god, “Trinity” also signified a powerful weapon, since “Trinity” was the codename for the test of the first nuclear weapon (the one that made Oppenheimer think of the quote, “Now I am become death, destroyer of worlds”).  Similarly, Trinity the character is the most powerful agent we see operating inside the Matrix in the original film, up until Neo comes into his power.  She too is a powerful weapon.

Comment: Wikipedia (which I agree with in this case) lists Trinity as the name of the nuclear weapons *test*, not the weapon.

Comment: @OwenReynolds Correct, and that's why that's what my answer says.

Comment: You start and end by saying Trinity is the name of a real-world weapon, which is not true. You write how it's the name of the test but then are like "weapon, weapons test -- same thing". But it's not. The Trinity test was an event, and a place in the desert, and an experiment, and a huge construction project. There's a semi-famous video game about it. That may have influenced the characters name, but not as in "she's like that bomb". It would have been "she's like that huge dangerous experiment".

Answer (score 3):

I don't have a primary source for this, but would like to share the first thing I think of regarding the meaning of Trinity's name. And, as one answer mentions, Carrie-Anne Moss states, "it can mean whatever you want it to mean."

I'm reminded of the scene in the first Matrix movie where Neo (Son of Man) dies at the end. Trinity rejects his death, confessing her love for him. For some reason, this love alone was powerful enough (at least from what we understood at the time) to bring Neo back to life.

To me, this can be said to model what happened to Jesus when He died. Depending on how you interpret the relationship between God (the Father) and the Holy Spirit, the bible describes that God raised His Son from the dead through the power of the Holy Spirit, the 2 parts of the Trinity bringing back to life the 3rd part.

---

Some references:

[Ephesians 1:19-20](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Ephesians%201&version=NASB) "and what is the boundless greatness of His power toward us who believe. These are in accordance with the **working of the strength of His might**  which He brought about in Christ, **when He raised Him from the dead** and seated Him at His right hand in the heavenly places,"

[Romans 8:9-11](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=romans%208%3A9-11&version=NASB) (You can say this is how the process of resurrection works, in part) "However, you are not in the flesh but in the Spirit, if indeed the Spirit of God dwells in you. But if anyone does not have the Spirit of Christ, he does not belong to Him. If Christ is in you, though the body is dead because of sin, yet the spirit is alive because of righteousness. But if **the Spirit of Him** who raised Jesus from the dead dwells in you, He who raised Christ Jesus from the dead will **also give life to your mortal bodies through His Spirit who dwells in you**."

Comment: @DavidW Hi, no unfortunately not. I meant to convey that it was just me offering a possibility.

Comment: @DavidW This answer is fine and I've upvoted it (I encouraged it in the comments on the question). As I said in my question: "If the Wachowskis have not spoken on the matter I am also interested in educated guesses as to the significance of the name." None of the answers have turned up an answer from the Wachowskis themselves; the answer from Carrie-Anne Moss is a pretty close second, but this educated guess is good, too.

Comment: @Null Ah, so you did.  My bad for not reading all the way to the bottom of the question.  Sorry.

Comment: @DavidW No worries. It's easy to miss so I wanted to post the comment that this answer was good both for you and other users.

Answer (score 3):

The Wachowski brothers (now sisters) got Ken Wilber to do the director's commentary on the films - so not quite from the horse's mouth, but close. The 'meaning' of the trilogy (of course it has many meanings) is discussed [here](https://integrallife.com/many-meanings-matrix/), as follows:

> Thus, as Ken summarizes a more integral interpretation (that takes into account what is revealed in all three films), Zion represents body (filmed in blue tint), the Matrix represents mind (green tint), and the machines—this is the kicker revealed in part 3—represent spirit (golden tint). For those of you keeping track, this is indeed quite similar to the Great Nest of Being as taught by the world’s wisdom traditions, a spectrum of being and consciousness reaching from body to mind to spirit.
>
> Borrowing from the wisdom of Christian mysticism, “The flames of Hell are but God’s love denied,” and so an alienated and dissociated spirit manifests as an army of machines bent on destroying humankind. **It is only in the integration of body, mind, and spirit that all three are redeemed and peace returns**.

I think the numerous allusions to the number three all over the trilogy are mainly a reference to this. The human mind, body, and spirit are at war with one another. Each of them is crippled in isolation - the body without the mind is empty, unaware, sleep-walking through life, used as no more than a source of power like a battery. Living the life of the mind without the body is a miserable existence, no bodily pleasures. The spiritual life is at war with both the corruption of the body, for which it has bottomless contempt, and the moral rebellion of the secular mind, in which it sees its own destruction. But the war cannot be ended by any one triumphing over and destroying the other two, but only by making peace between them, tolerating differences, letting people make their own choices.

It's also worth considering Lilly Wachowski referring to the films as an allegory for being transgender (mind and body at war...). There are subtle references to the *binary*, and the attempts to escape from it. Ther word 'Cypher' originally meant zero, 'Neo' of course is 'The One', 'Switch' might be a reference to to something that can be in two states, a binary bit, (the character of Switch was originally meant to be explicitly trans, female inside the matrix and male outside,) and 'Trinity' goes *beyond* the binary. You don't have to accept the binary this-or-that, red-pill-or-blue-pill, male-or-female, yin-or-yang options offered to you, you can take a third way. It's all about choice.

> Trinity : My name's Trinity.
>
> Neo : *The* Trinity? Who cracked the IRS d-base?
>
> Trinity : That was a long time ago.
>
> Neo : Jesus...
>
> Trinity : What?
>
> Neo : I just thought... you were a guy.
>
> Trinity : Most guys do.

A female hacker would probably have a thing about not fitting in to the conventional, binary choices on offer from society. Trinity is very much *not* a girly-girl - tough, gun-toting, competent at riding motorbikes and flying helicopters, short hair... And that's something that fits with the convention-breaking non-binary sex-role theme, as well.  Online, you see her *real* personality, her mind rather than her body. So it may be that her choice of hacker name was about going outside and beyond the binary choice. That's just my own speculation, though.

The Wachowskis *have* said that all the character names have *multiple* meanings, so there is almost certainly more to it, and they have deliberately chosen not to talk about it so as to leave room for people to find their own interpretations. There are lots of things that come in threes - it's a common trope in stories. Three witches, three wise men, three bears, ... There's something *satisfying* about the number. So there are lots of things it might refer to.